# Unpack binary file containing repetitions

Tags: ruby, binaryfiles

I have a binary file which stores numbers as repetition of two unsigned 32-bit integers followed by one unsigned 8-bit integer. I read this file as a string and want to decode it into an array of arrays, each containing three numbers. So I do this:

```
File.open("file", "r"){|f| f.read.unpack("LLC")}
```

However, this does not work, since it only handles the first three numbers in the file. This also doesn't work:

```
File.open("file", "r"){|f| f.read.unpack("LLC*")}
```

since it parses the rest of the file as 8-bit integers, and does not create an array of arrays. This is less critical since I can do it by hand, but I must repeat the LLC pattern.

Comment: This post was answered with "f.read.unpack('L*L*C*').each_slice(3).to_a". That's a great answer which does exactly what I need; please return the answer so I can vote for it.

Comment: After the post, I experimented, and found that it was wrong solution. giving wrong result.

Comment: For example, `"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06".unpack('L*L*C*').each_slice(3).to_a` yields `[[1, 2, 1027], [1280, 0, 6]]` while I expected `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`. (assume little endian)

Comment: That's very strange since for me it worked. What might cause the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
File.open("file", "rb") { |f|
  result = []
  while true
    data = f.read(9)
    break unless data && data.length == 9
    result << data.unpack('LLC')
  end
  result
}
```

BTW, use binary mode (`rb`).

---

ALTERNATIVE:

```
File.open("file", "rb") { |f|
  result = f.read.chars.each_slice(9).map { |data|
    data.join.unpack("LLC")
  }
}
```

---

```
"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06".chars.each_slice(9).map { |chs| chs.join.unpack("LLC") }
# => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```